# Jquery call webservice keep returning 0 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have tried a lot of different combination of settings, but it just seems not successful. Someone tried using .net app to call this, got positive return.

```
$('#btnCallService').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://asr.eduka.info/webservice/ASREmployeeTransfer.asmx/SendEmail',
                dataType: 'text',
                //data: "message='hello world.'&phone='0433085555'&name='Patrick Gan'&subject='Test'&emailFrom='fspatrick@hotmail.com'",
                data: { "message": "hello world.", "phone": "234234234", "name": "Patrick DFF", "subject": "Test", "emailFrom": "fasdfck@asdf.com" },
                //data:"{}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('abc');
                    $('#lblData').html(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status + ' ' + error.statusText);
                    console.log(error);
                },
                statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    alert( "page not found" );
                }
            }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType: 'json'
```

You're passing in a JSON object, not text. Either change to that or remove the line entirely as JSON is default.

```
data: { message: "hello world.", phone: "234234234", name: "Patrick DFF", subject: "Test", emailFrom: "fasdfck@asdf.com" },
```

Also I think the quotations around the property name need to all go.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. But have tried both of ways, does not work. And I guess "dataType" attribute is for the return value. contentType declares the data. Am I right?

Comment: Of course.. I must be tired. Can you get issue on jsfiddle or something?